# Hibernate проблема с SessionFactory

Tags: java, hibernate

При conection в базу, ошибка `NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.reflection.JPAMetadataProvider‌​.<init>(Lorg/hiberna‌​te/boot/spi/Metadata‌​BuildingOptions;)`

hibernateUtil :

public class HiberhateUtil {

```
private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;

   public static SessionFactory getSesssionFactory() {
try{
    // A SessionFactory is set up once for an application
     sessionFactory = new MetadataSources(new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().
                configure("hibenate.cfg.xml").build()).
                getMetadataBuilder().build().
                getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();

        return sessionFactory;
}
catch(Throwable ex){
    System.err.println("Session Factory creation failed: " + ex);
    throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
}
```

}
}

User :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    public static final String SELECT_USER_COUNT_BY_LOGIN = "select_user_count_by_login";

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "date", columnDefinition = "Integer", nullable = false)
    private int date;
    @Column(name = "name", columnDefinition = "varchar(255)", nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "userName", columnDefinition = "varchar(256)", nullable = false)
    private String userName;
    @Column(name = "password", columnDefinition = "varchar(256)", nullable = false)
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "country", columnDefinition = "varchar(256)", nullable = false)
    private String country;
    @Column(name = "phone", columnDefinition = "varchar(256)", nullable = false)
    private String phone;
    @Column(name = "email", columnDefinition = "varchar(256)", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;
```

xml :

```
 <hibernate-configuration>
        <session-factory>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:5432/personal?useSSL=false</property>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>

            <mapping class="users.User"></mapping>
            </session-factory>
    </hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Мой ответ неверный, AnnotationConfiguration deprecated

Comment: А как сейчас делают ?

Comment: Попробуйте  `new Configuration().configure("/hibenate.cfg.xml").addAnnotatedClass(User.class)`

Comment: а у вас случаем не spring?

Comment: нет, не spring, и нет метода `addAnnotatedC‌​lass`

Comment: Поправил ответ, поробуйте через `ServiceRegistry`

Answer (score 1):

```
    ну, во-первых, я не понял юмора с Вашей конфигурацией
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/personal</property>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    Вы что используете: постгрии или мускул? 
    Я так понимаю, что второй вариант. Меняйте настройки и обратите внмание на диалект. А потом напишите, каков результат выполнения...
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://...?useSSL=false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
А фабрику у хибернейта получают так:
SessionFactory sessionFactory = 
            new MetadataSources(new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().
                    configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").build()).
                    getMetadataBuilder().build().
                    getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
```

Comment: прошу прощения, ошибка`NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory` в                     .getMetadataBuilder()

Comment: ну , знаете ли...  у вас проблема с slf4j - это библиотека протоколирования. смотрите, какой джарник подключаете, а тут все зависит от системы сборки. Вот ссылка на репозиторий , откуда нужно качать https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.25 И пересмотрите свои импорты в классах.

Comment: Спасибо, но я уже подключал, и появилась ошьбка `NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.reflection.JPAMetadataProvider.<init>(Lorg/hibernate/boot/spi/MetadataBuildingOptions;)V`

Comment: Тогда обновите всю информацию, чтобы было видно, что именно вы уже переменили, иначе это гадание на кофейной гуще

Comment: Обновил игформацию в вопросе

Comment: Привел рабочий код код ниже.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static SessionFactory buildSessionAnnotationFactory() {
    try {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure("/hibenate.cfg.xml");

        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

        return sessionFactory;
    }
    catch (Throwable ex) {
        // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: пробовал, не подходит

Comment: а, что пишет, после изменения?

Comment: `java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError` в етой строке `sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration()`

Comment: У buildSessionFactory нет входньх параметров

Comment: а вы какую `Configuration` импортируете?

Comment: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration

Comment: Так, а какая версия hibernate?

Comment: Обновил до последней, параметрь принемает. Но в строке `.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);` ошибка `NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory`

Answer (score 0):

```
package users;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        User user = new User
        (111, "TestName", "TestUserName", "TestPassword", "TestCountry", "TestPhone", "TestEmail");

        SessionFactory sesssionFactory = getSesssionFactory();
        Session session = sesssionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.saveOrUpdate("User", user);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
        sesssionFactory.close();
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSesssionFactory() {
        try {
            SessionFactory sessionFactory
                    = new MetadataSources(new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().
                            configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").build()).
                            getMetadataBuilder().build().
                            getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();

            return sessionFactory;
        } catch (HibernateException ex) {
            System.err.println("Session Factory creation failed: " + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }

    }
}


package users;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    public static final String SELECT_USER_COUNT_BY_LOGIN = "select_user_count_by_login";

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "date", columnDefinition = "Integer", nullable = false)
    private int date;
    @Column(name = "name", columnDefinition = "varchar(255)", nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "userName", columnDefinition = "varchar(256)", nullable = false)
    private String userName;
    @Column(name = "password", columnDefinition = "varchar(256)", nullable = false)
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "country", columnDefinition = "varchar(256)", nullable = false)
    private String country;
    @Column(name = "phone", columnDefinition = "varchar(256)", nullable = false)
    private String phone;
    @Column(name = "email", columnDefinition = "varchar(256)", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;

    public User() {}

    public User(int date, String name, String userName, String password, String country, String phone, String email) {
        this.date = date;
        this.name = name;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
        this.country = country;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(int date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

}

<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:5432/personal?useSSL=false</property>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">false</property>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</property>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql">false</property>
      <property name="connection.pool_size">10</property>
      <mapping class="users.User"></mapping>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>

и зависимости градла
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '5.2.10.Final'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-validator', version: '6.0.2.Final'
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '5.1.43'
}

так все будет работать
```

Comment: спасиба, но здесь все то же самое, у меня та же ошибка

Comment: вы этот код пробовали? я его у себя запускаю и все работает. http://files.d-lan.dp.ua/download?file=b5ac9eeba3cf47e960935c4a73190a6c Качайте отсюда проект и пробуйте

Comment: Я так думаю что моя ошибка не связана с кодом, возможно что то в настройках нужно поменять.

Comment: ну так я вам для этого и даю рабочий проект. запускайте и сравнивайте. в чем вопрос то